# Need to grab the JSON here from an external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

This code does what I need but I want to store the JSON values it uses in a separate file using standard JSON format so the same data can be used elsewhere with getJSON requests.

(I need to run this to match up data returned from a getJSON request with additional values. I use the id to do the match on returned items. This is how I build the complete HTML items I need.)

CODE SAMPLE

```
$(function() {

    var json = {
   "nwsltrs":[

      {
         "id":"53c57dede4b07621dafde5d1",
         "nwsltrNames":"Hello",
          "author":"Joe"

      } // these entries will grow to a hundred or more.
   ]

    };

var titleID = "53c57dede4b07621dafde5d1"; // in actual code getting this value from a separate getJSON call

    $.each(json.nwsltrs, function(i, v) {
        if (v.id === titleID ){
            nwsltrName = v.nwsltrNames;
            author = v.author;
            console.log(nwsltrName + ":" + author);
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Want the external JSON file to look like this with and use .json extension:

```
{
   "nwsltrs":[

      {
         "id":"53c57dede4b07621dafde5d1",
         "nwsltrNames":"Hello",
         "author":"Joe",

      },
      {
         "id":"54b57dede4b07621dafde5d2",
         "nwsltrNames":"Bye",
         "author":"Mary",

      } // these entries will grow to a hundred or more.
]
```

I'm sure there are better ways to approach this and am open to hearing them—as long as I can use an external JSON file.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @charlietfl How do I modify that specific code sample so it will work with an external JSON file?

Comment: @dandavis Really, there is?

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for your input. The code is inside of a getJSON now and my attempts to nest failed. So, I'm posting the question as is. If you chose to add no value, please stay out of the way with the snarks. Thanks!

Comment: i was going more for cute than snark, but i didn't see any use of or your comment about getJSON (it's scrolled off-screen in the code box), so i see how it came off now. i'm a bit confused about the question; if getJSON works to get the ID, why wouldn't it work to get the data?

Comment: @dandavis No worries. One of the JSON files is retrieved from a remote server and cannot be edited. The other JSON data is local and used to expand on the data that's remote. It adds additional useful stuff. For example, the remote stuff has untitled text so I add that and other useful bits for the user. HTH

Comment: what do you mean by local, a file from the device, a file on the server of the page, or something else?

Comment: @dandavis Sorry, "local" as in my control served by my host along with other pages. And, updated with new JSON entries by me as necessary.

Comment: if you prepend "X=" in your json file, you can link it as a script and it will be ready right away as _X_ without jquery issues. without seeing the broken getJSON call, it's hard to say why that's not working.

Comment: @dandavis Can you show me by code example? Would that cause problems with other getJSON requests to same file (as noted in original question above)?

Comment: @dandavis I did try that before and it worked but caused a problem elsehwere (can't recall exactly what). Anyway, will try that route again including a test of the getJSON against the file with the x = treatment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63683/discussion-between-user1452893-and-dandavis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Moved getJSON request that was tried earlier before posting.

It needed to run and return the data prior to this .each.

This allows me to replace the local JSON function and use a validated external JSON file here and elsewhere as desired.